# my React.js Code not displaying in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, python-re

I'm a newbie on React and my React Code is not showing in my browser it's just blank what could be the problem?

[image: An image of it]

App.js file:

```
import React from 'react'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>E-commerce</div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

index.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM  from "react";

import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't look right.

```
import ReactDOM  from "react";
```

The ReactDOM should come from `react-dom` instead of `react, which means you should probably be able to get things working by updating that line to

```
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

Read more here https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html